# Is "A Short Elementary Proof of the Unprovability of the Collatz Conjecture" really as claimed?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, collatz-conjecture

The paper "A Short Elementary Proof of the Unprovability of the Collatz Conjecture", from a self-proclaimed peer reviewed journal (although the publisher, ScienceDomain International, appears on [Beall's list](https://scholarlyoa.com/publishers/)), purports to prove that the Collatz Conjecture is unprovable.

If it's valid, why has it not received more attention? If it’s invalid, what is the flaw, and why has it not been pointed out since initial publication?

Comment: See also [this meta most [referring to this question, 11-6-2016](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/25261/should-i-remove-a-link-if-given-an-external-request)

Comment: Giving a silent vote in favor of deleting this thread, because it does not IM(possibly misguided)O really add to the repository of knowledge we aspire to build. I will not cast that vote myself, because that would void a significant number of votes of regular users on the posts here. I prefer to keep the links in place. Deleting them does not really serve a purpose, because any interested party can still find them by viewing the edit history.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks in general terms as about the correctness of  a proof of a famous open problem, which is off-topic. (It also was closed already for a long time.)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The paper can be quickly identified as flawed by the simple fact that *it never discusses **which axioms** it claims that the Collatz Conjecture cannot be proved from*. This alone is proof positive that it cannot do what it purports to do.

If there had been a theorem stating, "The Collatz Conjecture cannot be proved in Peano Arithmetic" or "... in ZFC" or whatever, then some further investigation would be necessary. But the naked assertion that it "cannot be proved", without further specification, *is not a meaningful claim*. It's not even wrong.

The fact that the flaw is so fundamental also goes some way to explain why nobody has found it worth the effort to point it out in the pages of the journal.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Your criticism can be used to refute most math papers. For instance, did Wiles explicitly mention the axioms he used to prove FLT in his paper? (I'm not sure, but I think you get what I'm saying.) Furthermore, John Conway believes that the Collatz Conjecture is unprovable and he never explicitly mentions axioms in his paper. Check out http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.120.03.192?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: @CraigFeinstein: Claiming that a statement "cannot  proved" is fundamentally different from actually giving a proof. Most papers do not purport the former, and therefore have no need to discuss which axioms they claim are too weak to prove such-and-such. Also, _believing_ that the conjecture is unprovable is something fundamentally different from claiming to _prove_ it unprovable -- I'm sure that if Conway ever claims the latter, he would be open about which axioms it is he shows it for.

Comment: Actually, reading Conway's paper over again, he mentions the ZF axioms and extensions of it in the appendix. But I think my point is still valid. See Freeman Dyson's comment here: http://edge.org/q2005/q05_9.html Dyson never mentions any axioms.

Comment: I've made a couple minor (IMHO) edits here attempting to neutralise the tone of this answer. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I can't help but wonder why someone who earned (currently) a net $33$ upvotes answering this question feels he is objective enough to have voted first to undelete a question already deleted,  and then to  reopen a (previously closed) question (which garnered you 33 upvotes that, I gather, you don't want to lose.)

Comment: @amWhy: The rep didn't actually go away when the question was deleted. And from a strictly competitive point of view, reopening would certainly not be in my interest once I _have_ posted my answer; that only enables others to post _their_ competing answers.

Comment: @HenningMakholm  In my comment, I intended to address the vested interest you have in keeping this vote undeleted and reopened. I know very well that you won't lose your *currently acquired upvotes* (and I'm very **glad you won't lose them** if or when the question is deleted. But I still believe you have a conflict of interests here.

Answer (score 11):

I endorse Henning Makholm's points about the lack of any consideration of mathematical logic in the paper.

The form of the argument is also seriously flawed.  The author claims to prove (Theorem 3.3) that the Collatz process will take at least $d$ steps to terminate on input $2^{d+1}-1$. (It's not expressed like that, but that's what it says.) Given this, the author lets $d$ tend to $\infty$ and concludes (Corollary 3.4) that the process will never terminate if the binary expansion of its input comprises an unbounded list of $1$s. (Nowhere is it even mentioned how the Collatz process would proceed on such an input.) That the Collatz conjecture is unprovable is deduced from this "corollary" almost as an aside in the concluding paragraph by conflating a number of the form $n=2^u-1$ with one having "an unbounded number of binary digits".

Comment: Hmm, yes. So it looks like the author thinks he has actually _disproved_ the conjecture, but then for unknown reasons weakens this claim to "proved unprovable" in his title and abstract.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I don't see how proved unprovable is weaker than disproved? The latter doesn't imply the former.

Comment: @wythagoras: in a consistent logic, something that has been disproved is unprovable.

Comment: It's interesting to note that all my previous ( and also, unlike others' polite) comments on this post were deleted, including the one which pointed out that this answer still has a serious mistake concerning the exponent.

Comment: @arjafi If $d$ is not allowed to tend to $\infty$ (in the corollary), then the number of steps $d$ must be bounded, even though the theorem 3.3 is a statement for all $d>2$, where $d$ is unbounded.  That contradicts your argument for the supposed flaw you chose to mention.  As I originally pointed out before you came to this thread, the proper way to regard this is to acknowledge an infinity paradox instead.

Comment: @BeansonToast Corollary 3.4 makes no sense because the Collatz process has no meaning on an input of an "unbounded" (which to me means infinite) list of 1s. You can talk about the _limit_ of the number of steps as the list of 1s grows, but you cannot talk about the number of steps required on an unbounded list of 1s. This is analogous to the difference in calculus when talking about a function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ between $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)$ (which is meaningful, even if it doesn't exist) and $f(+\infty)$ (which is not meaningful as $+\infty$ is not in the domain of $f$).

Comment: @arjafi Indeed nobody has said that $d=\infty$. You have incorrectly assumed that an unbounded input is a single infinite input. The number of steps $d$ can still always be a finite number as $d\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @BeansonToast The Corollary explicitly states, "Assume that $n = 11\cdots 1$ contains an unbounded number of binary digits". By the "proof" there is an assumption of continuity here, but continuity at a point where the underlying function is not defined. (And according to normal mathematical parlance, "unbounded" in this case would be understood to mean "infinite", since any finite string $11...1$ is _a priori_ **bounded**.) I don't expect it will be worth my while to continue this discussion with you.

Comment: @arjafi The natural numbers form an infinite set (which is unbounded) but they can each be regarded as finite.  If you acknowledged this, then you would realize that **an unbounded input is not necessarily infinite**.  I don't want to have to repeat myself again, and it seems you are not prepared to admit this fatal flaw in your reasoning (which should certainly not be confused with common mathematical parlance). .